# Looking for a software to optimize production in a cafe

Tags: productivity

**EDIT:** Producing using Lean approach - that is on demand - is not feasible for us currently for number of reasons,e.g. employees apart from producing batches need to do other duties.

We have a small cafe where along with coffee we produce and sell sandwiches, breads and small treats. We produce them in batches several times a day and put them on vitrine. They have limited shelf-live (4 to 12 hours). I am looking for a software  that can:

1. Optimize production schedule to minimize losses (due to limited shelf life) and maximize profit
2. Generate reports for trashes/sells/produces of products, that we need to give authorities for quality control.

Most of profit is lost from trashing unsold products. The losses during production process -  ingredients,etc. are not important. Therefore we probably just need to know optimal production schedule.

This could be integrated in POS (preferred) or be a standalone system.

Common POS seems to take in account only transactions, e.g. [this](http://www.ncr.com/retail/petroleum-convenience/touch-points-sales-channels/food-service/pos-terminals). But they know nothing about producing the products that are on the shelf.
Software like [this](http://www.foodsoftware.com/Product_0008_01.asp?Keyword=&ViewMode=Public&NavURLs=Catalog%2Easp%3FViewMode%3DPublic%26ProductClassID%3D18%7CProduct_0008_01%2Easp%3FKeyword%3D%26ViewMode%3DPublic&NavNames=Product+Catalog%7C_IPro+Series+40+Restaurant+Inventory%2C+Recipe+%26+Menu+Software) seems to provides only insights on cost of production but does not aim to help to optimize batch production plan.

Comment: If you have an issue with waste perhaps you need to apply the Toyota's "Lean" approach to production. ie only make one kind of each sandwich and when that is sold make another to replace it. Perhaps in reality you may need a bigger buffer than one kind of each sandwich, but the idea is to remove waste by only producing goods when they are demanded. Initially you might find it too slow to make each sandwich as needed, so you would try and optimise that bottleneck and so on. There's an introduction here: http://www.lean.org/FuseTalk/Forum/Attachments/Deliciously%20lean.pdf

Comment: ... diagram of the process http://images.books24x7.com/bookimages/id_6223/figu12_1.jpg

Comment: Hello Matthew, thank you, that is also a good alternative. But with this approach employees need to dedicate more time producing, e.g. after each x sells they have to produce new products. And they have other duties in the petrol station where the cafe is. By producing only several times in a day with batches  they have time to do other duties and not always be ready to produce another sandwich. Also it is easier to control when each sandwich needs to be trashed by producing in batches.

Comment: So we would stay with producing batches.

Comment: Yes you produce "just in time", so after one has been sold, or just when one is ordered depending on how long it takes. Customer demand (pull) then sets the speed or flow of the process rather than trying to predict the demand. The art of Lean Production is to work out how to optimise the production process so it's as fast as possible, and/or the minimum size of a batch that you can get away with. You might enjoy reading about the history of the Toyota Production System to see how they solved this problem for car productions.

Comment: We probably cannot afford constantly producing products. Anyway, are you aware of any software implementing Lean Production particularly for cafe case?

Comment: The only Lean Production software I've used is http://leankit.com/ or https://trello.com/ mainly to make a kanban system to visualise and trigger the flow of tasks